# LauncherPro Shortcut Creator Guide & Repository?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, launcherpro

Anyone know of a good guide on how to use the [LauncherPro Shortcut Creator](http://www.launcherpro.com/shortcutcreator/) and/or a good source for already made shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check out his blog post on it.](http://www.launcherpro.com/2010/08/)

> LauncherPro Shortcuts are a new way of
>   creating, adding, and sharing custom
>   shortcuts for LauncherPro. Shortcuts
>   are created and shared as LPS files.
>
> LPS files are self-contained shortcut
>   files that have all the info needed to
>   make a shortcut, including the label,
>   icon, and Android intent (more on
>   intents in a bit). They are written in
>   a new format that I created for this
>   purpose, which is based in XML. Don’t
>   worry, I created a web-based tool for
>   creating these files so it’s as easy
>   as filling out a form and downloading
>   the resulting .lps file.
>
> A shortcut
>   always needs an Android intent to be
>   “executed” when the shortcut is
>   clicked. Intents are the standard way
>   of launching activities/apps and
>   sending information and commands to
>   apps in Android. If you want to create
>   your own LauncherPro Shortcuts, [please
>   read this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for a detailed
>   explanation of how intents work and
>   how to make your own.
>
> LPS files need
>   to be stored in your SD card, either
>   in the root of the card, or inside the
>   folders “download”, “downloads” or
>   “lpshortcuts”. To add an LP Shortcut
>   to a homescreen, long-press on a blank
>   spot, choose “Shortcuts” and then
>   “LauncherPro Shortcuts”. If you have
>   any LPS files in the previously
>   mentioned folders in your SD card,
>   they should show up on the list. You
>   can click on “Create New” to go to the
>   web-based LauncherPro Shortcut Creator
>   tool. You can also access the
>   LauncherPro Shortcut Creator tool from
>   your computer, and then put the
>   generated LPS file in your SD card.

[He also links to a lengthy forum thread where people are posting some of their shortcuts.](http://www.launcherpro.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2587)  I can't seem to find any other resources of shortcuts.

Comment: Ooops, I don't know how I missed the blog post.  Thanks for pointing this out.  I did see that forum post which is title "Share your custom LauncherPro Shortcut files!" but is 16 pages of people asking how to make shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could: Long press the shortcut icon you want to change. It brings up the "Edit dock shortcuts" list. Then choose "Change shortcut". After that select "Applications" (the icon with the android in the lower right corner) from the list. A menu with all your installed apps comes up, and you just have to click on the shortcut you want. In the end you will be asked if you would like to chamge the shortcut icon, between the default, launcher pro or custom icon.